Centrepetal force at the north or south pole
If you're, for example, 5 m away from the geographic north or south pole, gravitational force points inward, but centrepetal force points almost directly perpendicular, out into space. In that case, the centrepital acceleration would be
$a = \frac{v^2}{r}=r\omega^2$
The angular velocity $\omega$ is
$\omega = \frac{2\pi}{T}$
and the period $T$ is
$T = 24 * 60* 60 = 86400$
so $\omega=7\times 10^{-5}$
at a position $r= 5$ m away from the pole,
$a = 3.5\times 10^{-4}$ $m/s^2$
That's still a tiny acceleration.
But now consider $r = 100$ nm = $10^{-7}$ m
At that distance,
$a = 700$ $m/s^2$
Which is actually quite large, especially considering that the distance from the north pole is only $100 nm$!!!
On this scale, I guess it must be quantum effects binding the atoms to the earth? But does it significantly stretch the molecules so that their emission or absorption bands are different for example, or give them a preferred orientation? Does that relate to why magnetic and geographic poles are aligned? Does this impact the spectrum or location of the aurora? Stupid question from someone who has no idea.

Centripetal force is the net inward force needed to maintain uniform circular motion, it's cause is the difference in forces felt by an object. You are probably mixing this up with centrifugal force.

centripetal force, as well as centrifugal force and the Coriolis force all depend on the frame of reference, so you need to define which one you're talking about. Common choices are ECI, ECEF, though you could do one spinning at 20,000 RPM if you want. Also 86,400s is a mean solar day, not a sidereal day.

You have made a very common error. $v$ varies with $r$; $\omega$ does not. Therefore, as $r\to0$, $a=r\omega^2\to 0$ as well.

Omg that’s not the mistake I made. The mistake I made was not my equations at all. It was some spectacularly terrible arithmetic. I apologize, this made sense at the time, but I think I must have posted it while I had seizure aura or was too exhausted. This is really embarrassing and not a good example of anything, either my thinking and work or this physics. Thank you!

I’ve received a little skepticism elsewhere about my statement that I’m disabled. I have Psychogenic Non Epileptic Seizures that are connected to migraines and I did not have a seizure at the time but I did have a bad migraine of the type associated with seizures (dizziness, confusion) within 6 hours before or after (I can’t remember) and I took seizure rescue meds. I also had an exhausting day. I’m sorry I used bad judgment in posting!!!

@StevenDorsher I'm just here for the physics; the reasoning behind the post isn't relevant to me or to answering the question. With that being said, I hope everything is well. This is a Q&A site, so there isn't a reason to apologize.
